# LL(*) versus PEG parsers : what is the difference?

Tags: parsing, antlr

I am wondering if ANTLR v3, which presents its internal parsing algorithm as "LL(*)" is fully representative of PEG (parsing expression grammar) parsers.

Is there a difference ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [ANTLR article](http://www.antlr.org/papers/LL-star-PLDI11.pdf) was wrong about PEG.

LL(*) is a subset of DCFG (Deterministic Context Free Grammar), which is a subset of CFG (Context Free Grammar).

PEG can express context sensitive grammars like `A{n}B{n}C{n}`, in which `A` and `B` and `C` all occur `n` times. Here's the definition:

```
s := &(x C) A+ y / ε
x := A x B / A B
y := B y C / B C
```

But there is no way to define such grammar in CFG (the proof involves pump lemma). So PEG is not subset CFG. Whether PEG is superset of CFG? I don't know.

Two key differences between LL(*) and PEG:

1. LL(*) can only lookahead a DFA pattern, while PEG can lookahead a recursive pattern. For example, in PEG you can lookahead nested parens while LL(*) can't.
2. The choice operator `/` in PEG is priority choice (or "possessive"), which means if you have rule `A / AB`, it never reaches the right hand side `AB`. In LL(*) for a rule `A | AB`, it is possible to match `AB`.

If you have a PEG grammar without a lookahead, or your lookahead pattern can be reduced into a DFA, then it can be translated into LL(*). If not, it is not possible.

Comment: Your PEG-grammar is not yet right. It will also parse A{n}B{n+1}C{n+1}.

Comment: @CoronA Thanks for pointing out, I edited the answer with updated grammar to ensure a C happens right after A{n}B{n}.

Answer (score 4):

In ANTLR you can enable global backtracking on all production rules in your grammar, so that for `k >= 1` you could parse pretty much the same as PEG's. Of course, because of all the potential backtracking, the run-time of the parser degrades. At the cost of (some) memory you could also enable memoization, making it behave like a Packrat-parser, able to parse the input in linear time.

So no, there's not much difference w.r.t ANTLR and PEG/Packrat (with the right options enabled!).

Answer (score 3):

ANTLR and PEG are not the same. It is pretty theoretical question, and I think it will be the best for you to refer to [this](http://www.antlr.org/papers/LL-star-PLDI11.pdf) paper wrote by Terrence Parr where he exactly points the differences between ANTLR and PEG and some advantages of ANTLR LL(*) parsing strategy. I don't want to give myself freedom to paraphrase what he wrote there, but it is better for you to read the whole paper.

Answer (score 1):

According to the tools listed [here](http://bford.info/packrat/) ANTLR is a full representative of a PEG parser:

> ANTLR, a well-established parser generator by Terence Parr, supports extensive PEG features and combines packrat parsing with LL parsing techniques.

Comment: There exist some left-recursive Packrat extensions, which are, apparently, not supported by ANTLR.